# description of a Wiener Process assuming a Laplace Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, stochastic-processes

Is there a description of the Wiener Process when a Laplace distribution is assumed rather than a normal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiener process is defined as a process having normal/Gaussian increments. If you assume a Laplace distribution then it is called a [Lévy process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process). Note that the class of Lévy processes is much wider and allows for various distributions of the increments.

Comment: Hi @cardinal, are you sure? I have to check but e.g. here they say it is: http://neutrino.aquaphoenix.com/ReactionDiffusion/SERC4chap2.pdf

Comment: Do you have any reference @cardinal?

Comment: (+1) You are correct, Richard. I'm not sure what I was thinking about when I wrote that comment (perhaps [stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution)), but, at any rate, I've removed it. Cheers.